# mPDF - Page break based on element height

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, laravel-blade, mpdf

I'm using [mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) in Laravel and with [this package](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf)  version 4.0

The problem is that I have a list of questions in different heights which have 4 options, and I don't know the exact and  approximate height of every div tag which question and answer options are there, I don't want some part of my question to go to another page

All parts of my question have to be on **one page** and if this couldn't happen, mpdf put that question tag element on the next page (all parts of questions)

this picture is for now which is wrong:

[image: sample question lists]

what I want:

[This image](https://s4.uupload.ir/files/new_2_8ey8.jpg)

so for this problem, I want to know the height of my question element so I can determine if the new page is needed to add a page break(same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723448/mpdf-determine-height-of-a-element-after-rendering) on StackOverflow), or any other solution to fix my issue

this is my blade file:

```html
@php
    error_reporting(0);
@endphp

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>سوالات</title>

    <style>
        html, body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'fa', sans-serif;
            direction: rtl;
        }

        .main-container{
            padding:20mm;
        }

        @page {
            footer: pagefooter;
            margin-top: 0pt;
        }

        @page:first {
            header: firstheader;
            margin-bottom: 200pt;
        }

        .item-answer{
            display: inline !important;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .sub-item-answer{
            float: left;
            display: inline !important;
            margin-top: 0 !important;
            padding-top: 0 !important;
            height: auto !important;
            margin-bottom: auto !important;
        }

        .sub-item-answer-num{
            width: 5%;
            float:right;
        }

        .q_1{
            margin-top: 45px !important;
        }

        .question{
            display: inline-block;
            page-break-inside: avoid !important;
            position: relative;
            float:right;
        }

        .question-row{
            display: inline !important;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .question-number{
            padding: 5px;
            background: #bebe27;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width:10% !important;
            text-align: center;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .main-question{
            width: 95% !important;
        }

        .row {
            margin-left: -15mm;
            margin-right: -15mm;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
@php
    $i = 0;

@endphp

<htmlpageheader name="pageheader" style="display:none"></htmlpageheader>

<htmlpageheader name="firstheader">
    <img style="width: 100%;height:fit-content" src="http://api.amoozeshmelli.com/images/pdf/header.png" alt="header">
</htmlpageheader>

<sethtmlpageheader name="firstheader" value="on" show-this-page="1"/>

<sethtmlpageheader name="pageheader" value="on"/>

<div class="main-container container-fluid">

    @foreach($data as $question)
        @php
            $i++;
            $j=0;
        @endphp

        <div style="page-break-inside: avoid !important;" class="question q_{{$i}}">

            <div class="row question-row">

                <div class="question-number col-sm-1"> سوال{{$i}} </div>

                <div class="main-question col-sm-11">
                    @if($question->title)

                        {!! $question->title !!}

                        @if($question->image_url)
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{$question->image_url}}" alt="test">
                        @endif
                    @else
                        @if($question->image_url)
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{$question->image_url}}" alt="test">
                        @endif
                    @endif
                </div>

            </div>

            @if($question->options)
                <div class="question-main-container" style="float: right">
                    @foreach($question->options as $option)
                        @php
                            $j++;
                        @endphp
                        <div class="item-answer center-block row">
                            <div class="sub-item-answer-num col-sm-1">{{$j}})</div>
                            @if($option->title)
                                <div class="sub-item-answer col-sm-11">
                                    {!! $option->title !!}
                                    @if($option->image_url)
                                        <img style="width: auto; height:80px;" src="{{$option->image_url}}" alt="test" />
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            @else
                                @if($option->image_url)
                                    <div class="sub-item-answer col-sm-11">
                                        <img style="width: auto; height:80px;" src="{{$option->image_url}}" alt="test" />
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>

            @endif
            <hr>
        </div>
    @endforeach


</div>



<htmlpagefooter name="pagefooter">
    <p style="text-align: center;direction: rtl;">
        صفحه {PAGENO}
    </p>

    <img src="http://api.amoozeshmelli.com/images/pdf/footer.png" alt="header" style="z-index: 0 !important;width: 100%;">
</htmlpagefooter>

</body>
</html>
```

and I tried all methods in the [documentation of mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747923/10079059) but results were not useful

if any other solution exists please guide me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of tries, the issue solved!

the `page-break-inside: avoid;` doesn't work when I have a loop of block elements

I used a table for every question and put it in the main table and in it's `<td>` tag, the inner table now has `autosize="1"` which was needed

also, add this config to mPdf

```
$pdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
```

I added `page-break-inside: avoid` to the main table and the `<tr>` of questions in the loop

note that if you faced [undefined index error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319969/mpdf-undefined-index-error) try to solve it generally! but if like me, it doesn't fixed use `error_reporting(0);`

the corrected blade file:

```html
@php
    error_reporting(0);
@endphp

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>سوالات</title>

    <style>
        html, body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'fa', sans-serif;
            direction: rtl;
        }

        .main-container{
            padding:40mm 20mm 40mm 20mm;
        }

        @page {
            footer: pagefooter;
            margin-top: 0pt;
        }

        @page:first {
            header: firstheader;
            margin-bottom: 200pt;
        }

        .item-answer{
            display: inline !important;
            width: 100%;
        }

        p{
            font-size:35px;
        }

        .sub-item-answer{
            margin-top: 0 !important;
            padding-top: 0 !important;
            height: auto !important;
            margin-bottom: auto !important;
        }

        .sub-item-answer > img{
            width: 100% !important;
            min-height: 200px;
            max-height: 500px;
        }

        .sub-item-answer-num{
            width: 5%;
            font-size: 35px;
        }

        .q_1{
            margin-top: 45px !important;
        }

        .question-number{

            padding: 20px !important;
            background: #bebe27;
            border-radius: 10px !important;
            width:auto !important;
            text-align: center;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: auto;
            font-size: 35px;
        }


        .main-question{
            width: 95% !important;
            font-size:30px;
        }
        
        .main-question > p{
            font-size:30px !important;
        }

        .main-question > img{
            width: 100% !important;
            min-width: 800px !important;
            max-width: 1000px !important;
            min-height: 200px;
            max-height: 500px;
        }

        .row {
            margin-left: -15mm;
            margin-right: -15mm;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

@php
    $i = 0;
@endphp

<htmlpageheader name="pageheader" style="display:none"></htmlpageheader>

<htmlpageheader name="firstheader">
    <img style="width: 100%;height:fit-content" src="http://api.amoozeshmelli.com/images/pdf/header.png" alt="header">
</htmlpageheader>

<sethtmlpageheader name="firstheader" value="on" show-this-page="1"/>

<sethtmlpageheader name="pageheader" value="on"/>

<div class="main-container container-fluid">
    <table style="page-break-inside: avoid !important;">
        @foreach($data as $question)
            @php
                $i++;
                $j=0;
            @endphp
        <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid !important; min-height: 300px;">
            <td>
            <table autosize="1">
                <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td><span  class="question-number"> سوال{{$i}} </span></td>
              <td class="main-question col-sm-11">
                            @if($question->title)

                                {!! $question->title !!}

                                @if($question->image_url)
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{$question->image_url}}" alt="test">
                                @endif
                            @else
                                @if($question->image_url)
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{$question->image_url}}" alt="test">
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        </td>
        </tr>

                    @if($question->options)

                            @foreach($question->options as $option)
                                <tr>
                                @php
                                    $j++;
                                @endphp
                                    <td class="sub-item-answer-num col-sm-1">{{$j}})</td>
                                    @if($option->title)
                                        <td class="sub-item-answer col-sm-11" style="font-size:35px !important;">
                                            {!! $option->title !!}
                                            @if($option->image_url)
                                                <img style="width: 100% !important;min-height: 200px;max-height: 500px;" src="{{$option->image_url}}" alt="test" />
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                    @else
                                        @if($option->image_url)
                                            <td class="sub-item-answer col-sm-11">
                                                <img style="width: 100% !important;min-height: 200px;max-height: 500px;" src="{{$option->image_url}}" alt="test" />
                                            </td>
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                    @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        
    </table>
</div>



<htmlpagefooter name="pagefooter">

    <p style="text-align: left;direction: rtl; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 50px; padding-left:100px">
        صفحه {PAGENO}
    </p>
    <img src="http://api.amoozeshmelli.com/images/pdf/footer.png" alt="header" style="width: 100%;">

</htmlpagefooter>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `page-break-inside: avoid;` for your block (see https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened and as in documentation said it only works across max of 2 pages but I have lots of pages